# Как исполнить вторую команду, только если первая завершилась успешно?

Tags: bash, linux

Например, есть файл three.c:

```
int main() { return 3; }
```

Выполнив команду:

```
$ gcc three.c -o three ; ./three ; echo $?
```

я получаю

```
3
```

Если изменить файл three.c так:

```
int main() { return три; }
```

и снова выполнить команду:

```
$ gcc three.c -o three ; ./three ; echo $?
```

я получаю

```
...
three.c:2: error: stray ‘\270’ in program
3
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в случае ошибки gcc hello не вызывалось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя оператор логического И "&&", можно разрешить исполнение последующей команды только тогда, когда предыдущая удалась. В такой записи:

```
$ gcc three.c -o three && ./three ; echo $?
```

three выполнится при условии, что gcc выполнилась успешно, а echo выполнится в любом случае.